# Forcibly opening or otherwise impersonating a class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, jvm, final

I'm working in Kotlin, and I have a library that I can't modify (without maintaining my own fork of this huge and rapidly changing library).

There's a class in that library I need to instantiate, and it requires an instance of another class that does some stuff for it. I need to change how that second class works, so it feeds different information to the first class. But the second class is not `open`, and the first class asks for it by its full, non-`open` type.

How do I force my way into the non-`open` class and extend it anyway, against the desires of the library authors? Alternately, how do I cheat the type system to pass my own class off as an instance of the class the library is demanding?

Do I need to do some fiddling around at the JAR/build system level to replace the library's class files with my own versions? Can I use reflection to somehow impersonate the non-`open` class? Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: There isn't going to be any easy way to do this; I'd look more seriously for an alternative way to achieve your goals.  (For example, whether the library provides another way to do what you want, or whether there's a different library you can use.)  — You can't cheat the type system, nor extend a non-open class, nor replace a class at runtime.  You _might_ be able to replace the class at build time, but only if the package isn't sealed, and it'd be awkward, risky, and fragile.  (Or you could theoretically write your own classloader to hack that class, but that would be far more so…)